# Conceptually, is the a correct approach to using goroutines (and what's wrong with my code)

Tags: go

I have two question:

a) Does it make sense to spin up multiple goroutines in a loop for something like calculating a math result?

b) Why doesn't my code work (this is my first attempt at goroutines)? I'm guessing it has something to do with closing the channel.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    input := [][]int{
        []int{10, 9},
        []int{5, 2},
        []int{4, 9},
    }

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    c := make(chan int)
    for _, val := range input {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(coordinates []int, c chan int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            c <- calculateDistance(coordinates[0], coordinates[1])
        }(val, c)
    }
    distances := []int{}

    for val := range c {
        distances = append(distances, val)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(distances)
}

func calculateDistance(x int, y int) int {
    v := math.Exp2(float64(x)) + math.Exp2(float64(y))
    distance := math.Sqrt(v)
    return int(distance)
}
```

Playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/0iJ9hFnb8R

Comment: Clarify what you mean by "does not work".

Comment: fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.main()
 /tmp/sandbox241190633/main.go:27 +0x2e0

Comment: When you get it working, you can learn how to run benchmarks to see if it's worth using goroutines. As an opinion, this isn't really enough number crunching to make much difference. Usually you use goroutines when you are running some code that blocks, such as `io` from disk or network. The goroutine (possibly the main one) will block waiting for data, wasting time you could be doing something else with the idle CPU. https://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/30/how-to-write-benchmarks-in-go

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/zGEQGC9EIy

Comment: @RayfenWindspear Yes I agree that usually it would be IO work that would be concurrency candidates. I'll check out that Cheney post, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a) Yes it can make sense to spin up multiple go routines to do CPU bound tasks, if you have multiple CPU's.  Also it's super important to profile your code to see if there is actually any benefit.  You could use go's built in [benchmark](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Benchmarks) framework to help do this.

Because you're limited by CPU it could be a good start to do synchronously, then to bound your goroutines to the number of CPU cores instead of the # of items in your input list, but really it should be metrics driven to see.  Go provides amazing toolchain using benchmarks and [pprof](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/pprof/) to empirically determine what is the most efficient approach :)

b) https://play.golang.org/p/zGEQGC9EIy Your channel never closes and your main thread never end.  The example waits until all go routines finish their work, then closes the channel.

Comment: Thanks very much for the code edit and the suggestion to benchmark.

Answer (score 2):

range loops over channels terminate when the channel is closed. Since you never close the channel in your programm, the main goroutine will eventually block forever, trying to receive from c.

> Does it make sense to spin up multiple goroutines in a loop for something like calculating a math result?

Depends. If you haven't seen it yet, I can recommend Rob Pike's talk [Concurrency is not parallelism](https://blog.golang.org/concurrency-is-not-parallelism). This may give you some intuition about where it is beneficial, and where it isn't.